# Why are finite intersections (cylinder sets) of this form?

Tags: general-topology

I am referring to this article about [cylinder sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cylinder_set).

My questions concern the section "Definition for infinite products of finite, discrete sets".

1.) The $k$-th projection maps the $k$-th entry $x_k$ of the bi-infinite sequence $x$ onto the map containing $x_k$, i.e.
$$
p_k\colon \left\{0,1,...,n-1\right\}^{\mathbb{Z}}\to \left\{0,1,...,n-1\right\}, x\mapsto \left\{x_k\right\}?
$$
Since given any open set in $\left\{0,1,...,n-1\right\}$, f.e. the subset $\left\{0,1\right\}$, what would be the preimage under $p_k$? This only seems to make sense for subsets containing only one letter. This is why I ask how the $k$-th projection looks like.

2.) Why are intersections of finite many open cylinders (what the text then calls cylinder set) of the form
$$
C_t[a_0,...,a_m],
$$
where the positions are from $t$ to $t+m$, i.e without any gaps between them?

What is for example with the intersection $C_{-10}[0]\cap C_0[2]\cap C_{3}[2]$? This is an intersection of finite many open cylinders but the prescribed positions have gaps between each other...

Answer (score 1):

The preimage of $\{0,1\}$ under $p_k$ is

$$\left\{\langle x_m:m\in\Bbb Z\rangle\in\{0,\ldots,n-1\}^\Bbb Z:x_k\in\{0,1\}\right\}\;,$$

the set of all doubly infinite sequences whose terms come from the set $\{0,\ldots,n-1\}$ and whose term indexed by $k$ is $0$ or $1$. In the cylinder set notation that you’re using it is $C_k[0]\cup C_k[1]$.

$C_{-10}[0]\cap C_0[2]\cap C_3[2]$ is the set of sequences $\langle x_m:m\in\Bbb Z\rangle\in\{0,\ldots,n-1\}^{\Bbb Z}$ such that $x_{-10}=0$ and $x_0=x_3=2$:

$$C_{-10}[0]\cap C_0[2]\cap C_3[2]=\left\{\langle x_m:m\in\Bbb Z\rangle\in\{0,\ldots,n-1\}^\Bbb Z:x_{-10}=0\text{ and }x_0=x_3=2\right\}\;.$$

Comment: But why are intersections of finite many open cylinders of the form that the article gives? For example, why is $C_{-10}[0]\cap C_0[2]\cap C_3[2]$ of this form?

Comment: @Rhjg: They aren’t all of that form. They are, however, a finite union of sets of that form. In this case, for instance, you have $$\bigcup\{C_{-10}[0,a_1,\ldots,a_9,2,a_{10},a_{11},2]:a_1,\ldots,a_{11}\in\{0, \ldots,n-1\}\}\;.$$

Comment: I am wondering, since they say that the cylinder sets form a base. A base of the product topology is given by $\mathcal{B}=\left\{\bigcap_{k\in K}p_k^{-1}(O_k): K\subset\mathbb{Z}, \lvert K\rvert<\infty, O_k\subset\left\{0,1,...,n-1\right\}\right\}$.As far as I see, f.e. $C_{-10}[0]\cap C_{0}[2]\cap C_{3}[2]$ is in $\mathcal{B}$ but it isnt of the form $C_t[a_0,...,a_m]$! Or do I mean another base and the cylinder sets as claimed in the article, form another base?

Comment: @Rhjg: The cylinder sets as defined in the article form another base. This follows from my previous comment: every basic open set in the usual product sense is the union of finitely many cylinder sets.

Comment: Denoting the set of all cylinder sets as given in the article  by $\mathcal{C}$, then it surely is $\mathcal{C}\subset\mathcal{B}$, isn't it? But is also $\mathcal{B}\subset\mathcal{C}$?

Comment: @Rhjg: Yes, $\mathscr{C}\subseteq\mathscr{B}$. $\mathscr{B}\nsubseteq\mathscr{C}$, but $$\mathscr{B}\subseteq\left\{\bigcup\mathscr{F}:\mathscr{F}\subseteq\mathscr{C} \text{ and }\mathscr{F}\text{ is finite}\right\}\;,$$ so $\mathscr{B}$ and $\mathscr{C}$ generate the same topology.

Comment: Do not see the last point completely. Why does from this follow that they generate the same topology?

Comment: @Rhjg: It immediately implies that a subset of the product is a union of members of $\mathscr{B}$ if and only if it’s a union of members of $\mathscr{C}$.

Comment: Let $U$ be an open subset of the product, then $U=\bigcup_{i\in I}B_i$ for an index set $I$ and $B_i\in\mathcal{B}$. Each $B_i$ can be written as a finite union of elements in $\mathcal{C}$, i.e. $U=\bigcup_{i\in I}\bigcup_{j\in J}C_j$ with $J$ finite. And now?

Comment: @Rhjg: You’ve obviously written $U$ as a union of elements of $\mathscr{C}$. What’s the problem?

Comment: The problem is, that I do not see that. What are the elements of $\mathcal{C}$ here? Maybe its so obvious, I do not see. There are two unions.

Comment: @Rhjg: Each of the sets $C_j$ whose union you’re taking is a member of $\mathscr{C}$!

Comment: I am sorry, this probably is very stupid.. but.. there are two unions.. and I do not see it.

Comment: @Rhjg: For each $i\in I$ you have an index set $J_i$ such that $B_i=\bigcup_{j\in J_i}C_j$. Let $$K=\{\langle i,j\rangle:i\in I\text{ and }j\in J_i\}\;;$$ then $$U=\bigcup_{i\in I}B_i=\bigcup_{i\in I} \bigcup_{j\in J_i}C_j=\bigcup_{\langle i,j\rangle\in K}C_j$$ is a single union of elements of $\mathscr{C}$. A union of a union of members of $\mathscr{C}$ is still a union of members of $\mathscr{C}$. Write out a simple finite example or two.

Comment: Maybe one can just understand it in set theory language...if $x\in U$, then $x\in\bigcup_{j\in J_i}C_j$ for some $i\in I$. Since this is the case for each $x\in U$, U is an union of elements in $\mathcal{C}$.

Comment: @Rhjg: Yes, exactly.

Comment: This was the $\subset$ of the identity. On the other hand, if $x\in\bigcup_{i\in I}\bigcup_{j\in J_i}C_j$, then $x\in\bigcup_{j\in J_i}C_j$ for some $i\in I$, hence x in some B_i, and, since we supposed that $U=\bigcup_{i\in I}B_i$, $x\in U$. Right?

Comment: @Rhjg: Yes, that’s correct.